# Building Sql Project with TFS 2010 - error MSB4023

Tags: sql, msbuild

In our project we also have a SQL project so that we keep everything under source control. I've added two sproc's to the project and now I receive the following build error in [tfs2010](/questions/tagged/tfs2010), yet the project builds and deploys fine locally.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.Common.targets(92,18): 
error MSB4023: Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "Schema Objects\Schemas\<Schema Name>\Programmability\Stored Procedures\<sprocName>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first glance it appears that the build is failing because the build path is exceeding 260 characters.

I would start by looking at the path length. There are several solutions depending on your setup.

I have seen this error before if the project is upgraded as well.

What database project version are you using?

You could check to ensure that the build server is compiling the source of the VSDB project against the correct version you are using locally. [I bring this up because the new database tools might be trying to upgrade your project.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2011/11/21/top-vsdb-gt-ssdt-project-conversion-issues.aspx)

Hope this helps.

[Team Build and 260+ Character Paths](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/20/team-build-and-260-character-paths.aspx)

[Windows Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You sir, have saved me from buying more cakes :) I renamed my stupidly long build name to something shorter and it now works again. Thanks.